# RESTful DELETE php getting id?

Tags: rest

RESTful DELETE url is something like this "http://www.example.com/delete/1" which means we are going to delete the ID no 1, Is this mean that we must parse the URL so we can get the ID which is 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means both. It means that you are going to delete something identified as "1". Obviously, to do that, you'll need to parse the URL to get the identifier "1" out of the URL. Of course, if you've got URL rewriting going on, you can just pull that right out of the URL parameters.